# JavaScript in Zapier - Incorrect behavior of "IF" statement

Tags: javascript, zapier

I have a JS Task from Zapier that does some logic over the incoming data.

```
//if club member or joining - update points
var club = 0;
var points = 0;

if(inputData.existingMember || inputData.joiningClub == 'Yes') { 
    var club = 1; 
    var points = existingPoints+parseInt(inputData.amount,10)*0.1; 
}
```

I had "inputData.existingMember" as 0
and "inputData.joiningClub" as "No"

The if resulted as true and I had club=1 as a result.

I tested the script in a sandbox and it shouldn't go through. What's going on? I have no way of debugging it and don't know how is this happening.

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/b84p72q0/

Comment: If `existingMember` came out as a string then it'll always evaluate to `true`. Otherwise your code is fine and you'll need to show a runnable of the said issue as it can not be replicated.

Comment: If you can't debug it, can you add console.log(..) statements to see what inputData is at the time?

Comment: Yes, `"0"` is truthy, `0` is falsey.